# MySQL join - ordering results via another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 MySQL tables, one of which has a numeric column to orgainise the order I need the items to be displayed:

```
item_names

menu_id  |  dish_id  |  section_id  |  item_name
--------------------------------------------------
1        | 23        |      2       |   Pie       
1        | 24        |      2       |  Fish       
1        | 25        |      3       |  Apples     
1        | 26        |      2       |  Onions     
1        | 27        |      2       |  Chips

link_extras

extra_id |  dish_id  | sort  
-----------------------------
1        | 23        | 2     
2        | 23        | 2     
3        | 23        | 2      
1        | 24        | 0     
5        | 24        | 0     
6        | 26        | 3     
12       | 26        | 3     
1        | 27        | 1  
1        | 25        | 0
```

Basically what I am trying to do is extract each dish with a certain `menu_id` and `section_id` from the table `item_names` and order the output in respect to the `sort` column in the `link_extras` table.

so far:

```
$query="SELECT a.item_name, a.dish_id, b.sort
    FROM item_names AS a, link_extras AS b 
       WHERE a.menu_id='1'
           AND a.section_id='2'
           AND b.dish_id=a.dish_id
       GROUP BY b.dish_id
       ORDER BY b.sort";
```

I am quite new to databases so would appreciate any help. The result I am after is

```
Fish
Chips
Pie
Onions
```

Unfortunately just can't get the order correct.

Comment: there is no record for apple in the second table

Comment: Why is `Apples` coming in your result when `dish_id = 25` is not available in the table `link_extras`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake - will edit

Comment: Sorry about that - but it represents the `link_extras` table configuration more accurately - this brings into play the `section_id` column as ultimately I need to get the info in response to each section. Sorry for the inconvenience of the edit

Comment: @Sideshow - Yes I got why are you using `a.menu_id='1' AND a.section_id='2'` in the condition. So now your question is valid. :)

Comment: Why does each dish have multiple records in the _link_extras_ table? And is it guaranteed that where a dish has more than one record in the _link_extras_ table, they will have the same _sort_ number?

Comment: basically a dish can have several options related to it - and be used in several menu configurations. Admittedly this is confusing me as to the best practice of db design - much of which has been altered on the fly. At present as I am just prototyping an idea I understand the db will need restructuring should the project go ahead - however, even with a reasonable amount of planning the project is growing by the day... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.item_name, a.dish_id, b.sort
    FROM item_names AS a 
    JOIN link_extras AS b 
      ON a.dish_id = b.dish_id
   WHERE menu_id = 1
    AND section_id = 2
       GROUP BY b.dish_id
ORDER BY b.sort
```

Output:

```
| ITEM_NAME | DISH_ID | SORT |
------------------------------
|      Fish |      24 |    0 |
|     Chips |      27 |    1 |
|       Pie |      23 |    2 |
|    Onions |      26 |    3 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae1bd/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  in.item_name
FROM item_names AS in
  LEFT JOIN link_extras AS le
    ON le.dish_id = in.dish_id
WHERE in.menu_id = 1
    AND in.section_id = 2
ORDER BY le.sort
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ba8c/6)

Output

```
| ITEM_NAME |
-------------
|      Fish |
|     Chips |
|       Pie |
|    Onions |
```