# Mysql Order by with results of other table ( COUNT ROWS OF TABLE 2)

Tags: php, mysql

TABLE 1

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE public = 1 order by*****results of table 2****** ASC
```

table 2

```
SELECT * FROM abonnement where page_id = $page_id AND (date > NOW() OR gratis = 1)
```

COUNT ROWS TABLE 2 AND PUT IT IN TABLE 1 ORDER BY....

Comment: I am rather confused on what are you trying to do here.

Comment: use Join:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231234/mysql-join-ordering-results-via-another-table-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `group by` and a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM page p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT page_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM abonnement
      WHERE (date > NOW() OR gratis = 1)
      GROUP BY page_id
     ) a
     ON p.page_id = a.page_id
WHERE p.public = 1
ORDER BY a.cnt ASC;
```

The `left outer join` ensures that you do not lose any rows in `page` in case there are no matching rows in the second query.

Also note that I removed the condition `page_id = $page_id`.  That is replaced by the `on` clause.

I would also suggest include `a.cnt` in the `select` clause so you actually see the count.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.* 
from page p
inner join abonnement a on p.page_id = a.page_id
where p.public = 1 
and (a.date > NOW() OR a.gratis = 1)
order by count(a.id) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the he only needs use an update statement with a nested query inside it...

```
update table t2
 set count = (select count(*) from table1 t1 where t1.filed=t2.field and other conditions)
where other table2 conditions
```